# Ошибка при изменении версии .NET Framework

Tags: c#

С#. На Win7 создал проект изначально под .NET Framework 4, используя библиотеки Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel для работы с *.xls файлами. Все замечательно работало. На работе же оказался .NET Framework 3,5. В свойствах проекта целевой Framework выставил 3,5. После чего в процессе компиляции во второй приведенной строке

```
...
excelcells = excelworksheet.get_Range("A" + row.ToString(), Type.Missing);
int element = (Int32)excelcells.Value2; //тут
...
```

выдало исключение "System.InvalidCastException: 'Заданное приведение является недопустимым.' ". Непосредственно в ячейке екселя находится "1". Причина ошибки? Спасибо

Comment: Какой тип у value2 ?

Comment: @adrug Тип object. Формат ячейки в екселе "общий".

Comment: По дефолту общий тип это строка. Пробовал в строку кастануть, а потом int.parse  сделать?

Comment: Быть может со сменой версии пропала реализованная функции каста.

Comment: @adrug 1. Что такое каст? 2. Заменил на 'int element = Int32.Parse(excelcells.Value2.ToString());'. Ошибку на этой строке не выдало. Но, там надо другие аналогичные строки править. Тем не менее вопрос, почему так происходит? 3. Как в комментарии тут выделить код?

Comment: Какая-то двойная конвертация получается. Можно ли как-то избавиться от этого?

Comment: @puncher нажмите на справку рядом с кнопкой отправить `получится как у меня`

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, именно в версии .NET 4 появился `dynamic`, сильно упростивший работу с COM-объектами. Нутром чую, ответ на вопрос кроется в этом.

Comment: «После чего в процессе компиляции» + «выдало исключение "System.InvalidCastException» = не бывает. Исключение — это ситуация времени выполнения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каст (cast)  - [приведение типов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions). 
В экселе общий тип считается строкой. Можно воспользоваться следующей функцией. Она сама поймет какой тип вы ей отдали, но упадет если это нельзя превратить в число или вернет 0, [если значение будет null](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
int element = Convert.ToInt32(excelcells.Value2);
```

Comment: Простите, но string ссылочный тип. На него не распространяется боксинг. И что такое привидение типа на уровне библиотек?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников благодаря вам я знаю чуть больше чем ранее. Спасибо.
В качестве библиотек я имел  в виду реализованное явное приведение типа. Исправлю ответ, дабы люди не решили что мои слова истинные.